# Display to stdout AND set the last line as a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a variable based on the result of an application's output (terraform plan).

I need to display the output to stdout and then create a variable based on the last line.

I am able to get it to work if I tee the output to stderr or tty, like this:

```
CHANGES=$(terraform plan | tee /dev/stdout | tail -1)
```

However it MUST go to stdout.

Any suggestions are helpful

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Close. Your tail pipe is taking in `stdout` (that's what pipes do). You don't want your command to go to `stdout` (well, not only `stdout`), you want it to display to the terminal.

```
CHANGES=$(terraform plan | tee /dev/tty | tail -1)
```

This will print the *entire* `terraform plan` output to the terminal, and get `CHANGES` to only contain the last line. If you instead wanted only to get the last line of `terraform plan` into your variable and the terminal, it's probably easiest to just do

```
CHANGES=$(terraform plan | tail -1)
echo "$CHANGES"
```

Comment: I actually need it to display to stdout, /dev/tty won't work for this case. I got it to work with this, which I don't love, but oh well:   PLAN=$(terragrunt plan); echo "$PLAN"; CHANGES=$(echo "$PLAN" | tail -2); echo $CHANGES

Comment: You are correct, that is the only way to do that. You could consider wrapping your subshell commands $( ) in double quotes to better preserve whitespace, but otherwise that's pretty much the best you can do.